# Angular5 Selectbox open a Modal -> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

Hey Stackoverflow Community,

i found a weird problem and found a dirty workaround. 
Here the problem, i have a selectbox with some option. If the user select a specific option i show a modal box but here is the problem, when i open the modal right in the moment the user click on the option the error shows up. controle is here a FormControl of ReactiveForms

```
controle.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value === 'SOME_EQUALS') {
    this.modalService.open<SomeModalComponent>(SomeModalComponent);
  }
});
```

the exactly error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'.
```

the dirty workaround is that in the moment the value is quals what i expect i detach the ChangeDetectionRef then open the Modal and when i close the modal i reattach the cdr...

```
controle.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value === 'SOME_EQUALS') {
    // ChangeDetectionRef
    this.cdr.detach();

    const modal = this.modalService.open<SomeModalComponent>(SomeModalComponent);
    modal.onClose().subscribe(() => this.cdr.reattach());
    modal.onDismiss().subscribe(() => this.cdr.reattach());
  }
});
```

do u know a more beautiful way ?

Comment: Hey, can you reproduce the issue with stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use the Material library ?

If so, you have to bind to the change event of the checkbox :

```
@Output()
change: EventEmitter<MatCheckboxChange>

Event emitted when the checkbox's checked value changes.
```

By doing so, this should get rid of your error.

If not, you can still try to wrap your modal opening with a timeout :

```
setTimeout(() => this.modalService.open<SomeModalComponent>(SomeModalComponent));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use detectChanges():

```
controle.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if (value === 'SOME_EQUALS') {
        this.modalService.open < SomeModalComponent > (SomeModalComponent);
    }
}).add(() => {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem (with Angular 9). Without exactly understanding the underlying problem I found a relatively simple solution:
You can manually mark the form field as touched before opening the modal:

```
controle.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value === 'SOME_EQUALS') {
    this.controle.markAsTouched(); // to prevent ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
    this.modalService.open<SomeModalComponent>(SomeModalComponent);
  }
});
```